# IOS8: whole page scrolls down when input in fixed footer gets focus

Tags: html, ios, css, css-position, fixed

I have a problem with a fixed footer with an input field inside. The example you can find on http://dfitness.com.au/ page.The footer appears when you scroll down a little. Then if the input in the footer gets focus the whole page scrolls down. Why it happens? How to fix it?

p.s.: I can reproduce this bug only in the Safari on iPad and iPhone with iOS 8.

Comment: I have this problem too. Only occurs in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make body element fill 100% of width and height with hidden overflow. Then add additional div-container to the body and put all body's former content inside this div. Make the div scrollable. Now it's safe to put the fixed footer inside the body. It won't scroll.